# Delete the begin of a CString

Tags: c++, mfc, substring

I receive file paths in the form of a CString. For Example: C:\Program Files\Program\Maps\World\North-America

I need to remove everything before Maps. I.e C:\Program Files\Program\ but this file path could be different.

I tried:

```
CString noPath = fullPath;
fullPath.Truncate(fullPath.ReverseFind('Maps'));
noPath.Replace(_T(fullPath),_T(""));
```

Which doesn't work consistently. It's cutting some file paths in the wrong place. The solution doesn't need to use Truncate/Replace but I'm not sure how else to do this

Comment: 'Maps' should be "Maps"

Comment: Please provide a succinct problem description. What you have stated so far is subject to truncation on either side. That problem cannot be solved given the information we have.

Comment: You may get better luck if you change the tags from `C++` to `c++/cli`, or at least include the tag.

Comment: I've found that dealing with paths with windows stuff is kludgy, much less doing with CString. Once I started using `Boost Filesystem`, I've never looked back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CString` I'm familiar with doesn't have a `Truncate` member and `ReverseFind` only works with single characters, not substrings; so `fullPath`'s type is a mystery to me.

One thing I noticed: `_T(fullPath)` appears in your code, but the `_T` macro only works for literals (quoted strings or characters).

Anyway, here is a `CString`-only solution.

```
CString TruncatePath(CString path, CString subdir) {
    CString sub = path;
    const int index = sub.MakeReverse().Find(subdir.MakeReverse());
    return index == -1 ? path : path.Right(index + subdir.GetLength());
}
    ...

CString path     = _T("C:\\Program Files\\Program\\Maps\\World\\North-America");
CString sub_path = TruncatePath(path, _T("Maps\\"));
```

Gives you `sub_path`: `Maps\World\North-America`

Comment: I just needed to add 5 to the index so it would print Maps\World\North-America but this worked perfectly. Thank you

Comment: I updated the function so that subdir is now kept at the beginning of the returned truncated path.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Delete` function for this purpose.

for example:

```
CString path(_T("C:\\Program Files\\Program\\Maps\\World\\North-America"));
path.Delete(0, path.Find(_T("Maps")));  //pass first index and number of count to delete
```

Now variable `path` is having value `Maps\\World\\North-America`

Comment: This will fail in undefined ways in case the substring is not found. And the `CString::Find`-call will match substrings of directory names, too. This works for the sample input, but for not much more.